# how to compare parts of strings which contains int?

Tags: c++, string, integer

let's assume I have **this is an example**

```
string str1 = "programming 15"
string str1 = "programming 3"
```

if I used normal comparing like ==, <, >, the results will return programming 15 is smaller than programming 3.
But what if I wanted to compare the numbers like int not strings what to do ?
and what if it was string array ? **I mean the string length is variable** I used something like this to know if it contains the string part correct me if I'm wrong.

```
if(str1.find(str2) != std::string::npos)
```

this will return true since it actually contains part of it, or I think it will return true I didn't really test it with the number case I only tested it when it was a normal string with no numbers, thanks in advance.
Note: all of this comparing is in an ordered linked list, so I'm 100% sure that programming 3 will be right after programming 15 same for any other similar words but with different numbers at the end.
All the elements in the list are in the same format.

Comment: It is unclear whether all strings added to the list has the same shown format.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow yeah all the elements are int the same format
program 25
programmer 23
programming 15
programming 3
programs 23
this is part of the output

Comment: Pull the string apart and consider only the numeric portion. If the format is always word-space-number, this is easy to so with `std::istringstream stream(str); std::string discard; int val; stream >> discard >> val;`. If the format is more complicated but the number is always at the end, start at the end of the string and read backward until you have all of the number. If the number could be anywhere, consider having a long, loud talk with whoever came up with such an insane protocol.

Comment: @user4581301 no the number is always at the end .. i will try to use ur method, thanks :)

Comment: @user4581301 it actually helped and now I was able to replace 2 nodes.. thanks alot.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>
using namespace std;


int getNum(const string& s)
{
    regex reg("([0-9]+)");
    smatch match;
    
    if( std::regex_search(s.begin(), s.end(), match, reg) ){
        string numInStr = match[0]; 
        return stoi(numInStr);
    }
    
    return -1;
}

int main()
{
    regex reg("([0-9]+)");
    const string str1 = "programming 15";
    const string str2 = "programming 13";
    smatch match;
    
    cout << getNum(str1) << endl;
    cout << getNum(str2) << endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```